# Class Bug - NoneType and Int - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a coursework to do. I need to pass all the 6 tests that are required. I've passed 5, but having problem with one regarding the classes in Python.

```
def doomsday(y): 

    """
    >>> doomsday(2012)
    3
    >>> doomsday(1899)
    2
    >>> doomsday(1923)
    3
    >>> doomsday(10000)
    -1
    >>> doomsday(1756)
    -1
    >>> type(doomsday(2010))
    <class 'int'>
    """
    try:
        y
    except ValueError:
        return
    if y in range (1800, 1899+1):
        x = 5
        w = y%100
        a = w//12
        b = w%12
        c = b//4
        d = (a + b + c)%7
        t = x + d
        if t>6:
            t = t - 7
            print (t)
        else:
            print (t)

    elif y in range (1900, 1999+1):
        x = 3
        w = y%100
        a = w//12
        b = w%12
        c = b//4
        d = (a + b + c)%7
        t = x + d
        if t>6:
            t = t - 7
            print (t)
        else:
            print (t)
    elif y in range (2000, 2099+1):
        x = 2
        w = y%100
        a = w//12
        b = w%12
        c = b//4
        d = (a + b + c)%7
        t = x + d
        if t>6:
            t = t - 7
            print (t)
        else:
            print (t)

    elif y in range (2100, 2199+1):
        x = 0
        w = y%100
        a = w//12
        b = w%12
        c = b//4
        d = (a + b + c)%7
        t = x + d
        if t>6:
            t = t - 7
            print (t)
        else:
            print (t)

    else:
        x = -1
        print (x)
```

I cannot pass this test:

```
type(doomsday(2010))
    class 'int'
```

And the error is:

```
Failed example:
    type(doomsday(2010))
Expected:
    class 'int'
Got:
    0
    class 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Your function does not return anything, therefore an implicit return with a return value of `None` will take place. If you want your function to return an integer, you need to do it explicitly.

Comment: `print` is not `return`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bug is probably coming from the fact that you think `print()` returns some value. It does not.

Your function does not return anything, therefore an implicit return with a return value of None will take place. If you want your function to return an integer, you need to do it explicitly. i.e Replace your `print()`'s with `return`s

From the [Python Documentation on functions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions):

> [...] even functions without a return statement do return a value [...], **This value is called None (it’s a built-in name)**. Writing the value None is normally suppressed by the interpreter if it would be the only value written. [...]

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

def doomsday(y):

```
"""
>>> doomsday(2012)
3
>>> doomsday(1899)
2
>>> doomsday(1923)
3
>>> doomsday(10000)
-1
>>> doomsday(1756)
-1
>>> type(doomsday(2010))
<class 'int'>
"""
try:
    y
except ValueError:
    return
if y in range (1800, 1899+1):
    x = 5
    w = y%100
    a = w//12
    b = w%12
    c = b//4
    d = (a + b + c)%7
    t = x + d
    if t>6:
        t = t - 7
        return t
    else:
        return t

    etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to return values instead of printing them:

```
def doomsday(y): 

    """
    >>> doomsday(2012)
    3
    >>> doomsday(1899)
    2
    >>> doomsday(1923)
    3
    >>> doomsday(10000)
    -1
    >>> doomsday(1756)
    -1
    >>> type(doomsday(2010))
    <class 'int'>
    """
    try:
        y
    except ValueError:
        return
    if y in range (1800, 1899+1):
        x = 5
        w = y%100
        a = w//12
        b = w%12
        c = b//4
        d = (a + b + c)%7
        t = x + d
        if t>6:
            t = t - 7
            return t
        else:
            return t



    elif y in range (1900, 1999+1):
        x = 3
        w = y%100
        a = w//12
        b = w%12
        c = b//4
        d = (a + b + c)%7
        t = x + d
        if t>6:
            t = t - 7
            return t
        else:
            return t
    elif y in range (2000, 2099+1):
        x = 2
        w = y%100
        a = w//12
        b = w%12
        c = b//4
        d = (a + b + c)%7
        t = x + d
        if t>6:
            t = t - 7
            return t
        else:
            return t

    elif y in range (2100, 2199+1):
        x = 0
        w = y%100
        a = w//12
        b = w%12
        c = b//4
        d = (a + b + c)%7
        t = x + d
        if t>6:
            t = t - 7
            return t
        else:
            return t

    else:
        x = -1
        return x
```